# Выбрать строку с крайней датой через where. PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

Есть длинный запрос, в результате которого мы можем получить дубликаты во всех столбцах кроме одного-двух. Можно ли через where (принципиально важно именно в where) задать выборку по последней дате?
Подробнее в скриноште.
Как выбрать в общем запросе оставить все получаемые строки, а если есть одинаковые по некоторым столбцам - то выбрать только одну из них, которая последняя по дате.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: where date = (select max(date) from.... ) осталось описать правила поиска дубликатов в подзапросе

Comment: Спасибо, 
а можно ли выбрать, например, если брать скриншот за образец, Max c date 1/11/22 и Nevil c date 30/11/22? 
Ваш запрос даст только строки у которых одна дата - максимальная из какой-то таблицы. А если надо все с разными датами, а если есть дубликаты, то оставить только крайнюю дату из этих дубликатов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочтите в моем комментарии не только текст запроса, но и информацию после самого запроса.... __Осталось описать правила поиска дублей в подзапросе__ вам нужно явно установить поля по которым ищется дубль.... например так ```select * from xxx as x1 where x1.date = (select max(date) from xxx x2 where x1.YYY = x2.YYY)``` где YYY колонка(или группа колонок) для уникальности )